# Vectorize matrix multiplication along a given vector

Tags: python, numpy

In order to refactor parts of my code, I would like to vectorize some matrix multiplication by stacking vectors / matrices along a given dimension. Basically I would like to get rid of the for loop in the following code:

```
import numpy as np


test1 = np.array([1,2,3,4]).reshape(4,1)
test2 = np.array([5,6,7,8]).reshape(4,1)

vector = np.concatenate([test1, test2], axis=1)

matrix = np.zeros((2,2,4))
matrix[0,0,:] = np.ones((4,))
matrix[1,1,:] = np.ones((4,))*0.5

result = np.zeros(4)
for i in range(4):
    result[i] = vector[i,:] @ matrix[:,:,i] @ vector[i,:]
```

I tried using the np.dot but I can't get the input shapes to match correctly. I expect in the end (for the above code) a vector of length 4. I am quite a beginner in python, I apologize if this is straightforward :)

Comment: With `matmul/@` the first of 3 dimensions is the "batch" one, your `i`.  I'd recommend reading the `np.matmul` docs.  So `vector[:,None,:] @ matrix.transpose(2,0,1) @ vector[:,:,None]` should produce a (n,1,1) array.   But the `einsum` approach may be simpler to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the new axis to the `vector`, then do the multiplication and sum along `axis`:

```
vector_temp =vector[:,:,np.newaxis]

multi = vector_temp * matrix.T *vector_temp

result_temp = np.sum(np.sum(multi, axis=1), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing the math would help. I guess you want to compute

∑ⱼₖ vᵢⱼ Mⱼₖᵢ vᵢₖ

in this expression you are contracting two indices (j,k) but not i. So you can easily use `np.eigen`:

```
np.einsum('ij,jki,ik->i', vector, matrix, vector)
```